# Location block root overwritten by server root definition on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, config

I've been fighting with this 'issue' for a few days, and can't figure what's going on inside my nGinx server.

This is the server configuration that has become a nightmare for days

```
server {
  listen 80 ;
  listen       [::]:80;
  server_name  domain.com *. domain.com;

  root /data;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    location ~ \.json$ {
            add_header location micro;
            root /data/micro/public/;
            try_files  /index.html /index.php;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    root /data/micro/public/; 
                    try_files /index.php?$request_uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /data/micro/public/index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

    }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    add_header location php;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    add_header location general;
  } 
}
```

The idea is the json location matches any json request and, if the file doesn't exist, try with index.php (which will build that json file)
For any other file that don't match that location, it should match the root location.

This is the configuration for the 'main' log template:

```
        log_format main 'time_local="$time_local" site="$server_name" '
               'status="$status" uri_query="$query_string" uri_path="$uri" '
               'request_filename="$request_filename" request_uri="$request_uri" '
               'uri="$uri" realpath_root="$realpath_root" document_root="$document_root" ';
```

With this configuration, if I request

**domain.com/flowers.json**

it returns the index.php that is located at the root of the server document root

```
time_local="06/Sep/2020:18:51:56 +0000" site="domain.com" status="200" uri_query="" uri_path="/index.php" request_filename="/data/index.php" request_uri="/flowers.json" uri="/index.php" realpath_root="/data" document_root="/data"
```

If I try with domain.com/test.json, which exists, I get the same

```
time_local="06/Sep/2020:19:02:40 +0000" site="domain.com" status="200" uri_query="" uri_path="/index.php" request_filename="/data/index.php" request_uri="/test.json" uri="/index.php" realpath_root="/data" document_root="/data"
```

On the first case, I expected to have been served the index.php from the location document root directive, which is **/data/micro/public**; on the second case I expected to be served the **test.json** file from the same location. But it didn't work

I commented the **try_files** directive on the location json block

```
  location ~ \.json$ {
    add_header location micro;
    root /data/micro/public/;
    #try_files  /index.html /index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        [...]
    }
  }
```

Note that the **document_root** remains untouched, as I had defined before.

Now, if I try with

**domain.com/flowers.json**

I get

```
time_local="06/Sep/2020:19:06:26 +0000" site="domain.com" status="404" uri_query="-" uri_path="/sellers.json" request_filename="/data/micro_sellers/public/sellers.json" request_uri="/sellers.json" uri="/sellers.json" realpath_root="/data/micro_sellers/public" document_root="/data/micro_sellers/public"
```

and with

**domain.com/test.json**

I get

```
time_local="06/Sep/2020:19:06:34 +0000" site="tappx.com" status="200" uri_query="-" uri_path="/test.json" request_filename="/data/micro_sellers/public/test.json" request_uri="/test.json" uri="/test.json" realpath_root="/data/micro_sellers/public" document_root="/data/micro_sellers/public"
```

which is what I was expecting on the first configuration, but it keeps failing because directive try_files is not enabled and can't try with index.php when the json file does not exist.

**Oh, almost forgot**: note that I am using a header to check which location block matches; on the first two cases, the block matched is the PHP location; on the last two cases, it's matched the json location.

I have checked [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) from the nGinx documentation as well as the [official ngx_http_core_module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html); they have been helpful but not enough.

Does anyone have any idea of what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `try_files` the currently selected location is switched to another.

AFAIK, there will be no inheritance of directive while jumping/switching context using `try_files` (or at least so unless the jump ends up from a parent location to a nested location).

NGINX will ultimately use one final location for satisfying a request. *Which* directives "apply" to serving the request are the ones specified in that location and any inherited from upper levels (not from the jumped ones). Even then not everything inherited from the parent context (varies between specific directives greatly).

> The idea is the json location matches any json request and, if the file doesn't exist, try with index.php (which will build that json file).

But in your code you have:

```
try_files  /index.html /index.php;
```

Mind this rule to understand how `try_files` works: first arguments are checked for existence, and if they are, URI changed their path and location matching restarts. The *last* argument is only different that it never checked for existence and URI switched to it when all previous arguments do not exist as files.

So when a `.json` file does not exist, NGINX will simply check if a file `/index.html` doesn't exist (and as I understand it doesn't), then ultimately jump to `/index.php`.

The location search starts all over again. And it won't jump to the nested location as per your expectation. Just because the URL no longer matches `.json` extension. Thus it will land in `location ~ \.php$ {` on the server level, not the nested one. That location will inherit `root /data;`.

So all in all, this kind of nesting will never make sense:

```
location ~ \.json$ {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
```

Because it is impossible to have a filename which ends up with `.json` and `.php` extension at the same time :-)

What you probably want to do for the "generate if doesn't exist" approach in a more clear way is using named locations.

```
location ~ \.json$ {
    root /data/micro/public/; 
    try_files $uri @json_gen;
}

location @json_gen {
    root /data/micro/public/; 
    # do not include any try_files here for less surprises :)
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```